# Cardinality of a set of non-continuous functions

Tags: cardinals

I have to find the cardinality of the set of the non-continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

I think we should look for function that at least have a point of discontinuity, but i don't have a clue, really. Any hint?

Comment: One approach: There are "few" continuous functions, since a continuous function is determined by its values on the rationals. But there are lots of functions.

Answer (score 3):

You are starting in the wrong direction.  If you look at the definition of a function, almost every function is discontinuous.  We do a disservice to students when we say "plot a function on the board" and draw something continuous.  If you are coming up from below, there is only one value for $f(x)$ that makes the function continuous and continuum many that make it discontinuous.  Think about the total number of functions there are, and you can ignore the continuous ones.